# Forms of Schrödinger's equation

Tags: schroedinger-equation

I need to stress that I've been seeing and learning about Schrödinger's equation for **the very first time** in class. 
Just looking at the equation and even with some explanation, I understand about 20% of it all.
Which seems extremely daunting. What are the forms of the equation and what each one's purpose is. 
Maybe the solution is very simple but I cannot see it. So any kind of wisdom is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Griffith's book on introductory QM?

Comment: There is a time-dependent form and a time-independent form. Any QM textbook covers them.

Comment: *Just looking at the equation* It would help if you showed what form of the equation you have learned. Are you working in one dimension? Three dimensions? With a particular potential? An arbitrary potential? In the position representation? Using kets? Your question is vague and thus doesn’t have a good answer.

Comment: I studied and liked this book https://archive.org/details/ost-physics-schiff-quantummechanics/mode/1up?view=theater

Comment: *Which seems extremely daunting* Have you seen differential equations before? Is your version even written as a differential equation? Or does it look like an eigenequation in linear algebra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways of writing the Schrodinger equation, which stem from the mathematical fact that linear differential operators are connected to eigenvalue problems.

Since you have studied the Schroodinger equation for the first time in class, I will guess that the form you encountered was presented as a partial differential equation that may have been reffered to as a kind of "wave" equation:
$$-{\hbar^2\over 2m}\nabla^2\Psi(\vec r,t)+V(\vec r)\Psi(\vec r,t)=i\hbar{\partial\Psi(\vec r,t)\over\partial t}.$$ Here the three dimensional form is given, i.e. it is a function of $\vec r$, the one dimensional form would look like:
$$-{\hbar^2\over 2m}{\partial^2\Psi(x,t)\over\partial x^2}+V(x)\Psi(x,t)=i\hbar{\partial\Psi(x,t)\over\partial t}.$$ After applying the technique of "separation of variables", one arrives at the "time-independent" Schroidnger equation:
$$-{\hbar^2\over 2m}\nabla^2\psi(\vec r)+V(\vec r)\psi(\vec r)=E\psi(\vec r).$$ Where the $\nabla^2$ operator becomes a ${d^2\over dx^2}$ in the case of one dimension.

Now, the first equation I wrote, the time dependent Schrodinger equation can be written as an operator equation with the identities following:
$$\hat H=-{\hbar^2\over 2m}\nabla^2+V(\vec r);\quad \hat E=i\hbar{\partial\over\partial t}.$$
So that the Schrodinger equation becomes:
$$\hat H\Psi(\vec r,t)=\hat E\Psi(\vec r,t)$$ Since the solution to Schrodinger's equation is an element of an abstract vector space, i.e. *Hilbert space* one may write the above equation as a full fledged operator equation using Dirac notation for the Hilbert space vectors:
$$\hat H|\Psi(\vec r,t)\rangle=\hat E|\Psi(\vec r,t)\rangle.$$ Here the operator $\hat H$ is the "Hamiltonian". Further the time dependence may be written as a unitary transformation on the abstract vectors:
$$\hat H\;\mathcal U(t_0,t)|\psi(\vec r)\rangle=\hat E\;\mathcal U(t_0,t)|\psi(\vec r)\rangle.$$
The time independent form of the operator equation is written as:
$$\hat H|\psi(\vec r)\rangle=E|\psi(\vec r)\rangle.$$ This is the mathematical form referred to as the "eigenvalue" problem, and is often seen without the Drac dress as:
$$\hat H\psi=E\psi.$$
The Schrodinger equation has even more forms, for example one might choose to formulate the equation in the "Heisenberg picture", or one can write it as an integral equation utilizing the propagator, or Green's function for still more variation.